# How to increase body size limit in Express without body-parser?

Tags: express, amazon-s3, file-upload, nestjs

There is a NestJS app (with Express under the hood), which has controller for uploading files as a streams. Files are sent from Node.js app by reading as a stream and sending it with Axios:

```js
const data = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
await axios.post('/files/upload', data)
```

On the side of a NestJS app, the `req` object is used to access incoming file as a stream. Then this stream is added to S3's PutObjectCommand for further uploading:

```js
@Post('/upload')
async upload(@Req() req: Request) {
  await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: 'file-key',
    Body: req
  }));
}
```

The thing is that when uploading large file, NestJS throws an error: `[ExceptionsHandler] request entity too large PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`.

I've tried adding `express.urlencoded({ limit: '5gb', parameterLimit: Infinity })` as a middleware. This fixed the error but the app started consuming memory. It seems that it's because `urlencoded` parses the incoming request body and puts the file content as a buffer in `req.body`.

The question is — is it possible somehow to increase the request body size limit without parsing the incoming data and saving it to `req.body`? Or maybe I'm on a wrong way? Probably there is another approach for uploading files to S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that when using any of the body parsers, such as `express.urlencoded()` or `express.json()`, the body size limit is automatically set.

In order to send a file as a stream (which is a binary file) from a Node.js app to other Express-based app, this should be done with a header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. This way the above parsers will be skipped and stream from `req` object can be directly used (without parsing stream and consuming memory).